# Adding a new tag to the Mathematica forum

Tags: support, tagging

How are new tags added to the Mathematica forum?

Lately I've been working with celltags in Mathematica, and there have been quite a few questions on them in this forum.  I think they are important enough to have their own tag in the forum.  What is the procedure for requesting this?  I am assuming someone is control of these tags so they don't get out of control.

Comment: I think questions about `CellTags` are covered under the [tag:cells] tag. If you are looking for questions specifically about `CellTags`, you can find them using [search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=[cells]+celltags+is%3Aquestion). In my opinion tag names should be names of topics and **not** the names of Mathematica functions or options for functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a tag by typing the intended name of the new tag alongside the other (autocompleted) existing tags in the question ([source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)), so the system does not require you to make a request or anything like that. On the other hand, I suppose it can be nice to post here on meta that you want to add a new tag to get some feedback. There are quite a few Q&A's on meta about reorganising tags, so it may be nice to have some discussion before adding a new tag, to get it right on the first try.

Note that you need to have at least 300 reputation points to create a new tag, which is not a problem in your case. See also this [privilege/reputation table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).